# Find Duplicate Entity tag from XML using java

Tags: java, xml, dom, xml-parsing

In a XML file Some entity are declared

for exp:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--Arbortext, Inc., 1988-2004, v.4002-->
<!DOCTYPE test PUBLIC "-//Atul//DTD ATM - TEST//EN//-"
 "test.dtd" [
<!ENTITY ent1 SYSTEM "Graphic/test1.txt" NDATA ccitt4>
<!ENTITY ent1 SYSTEM "Graphic/test1.txt" NDATA ccitt4>
<!ENTITY ent2 SYSTEM "Graphic/test2.txt" NDATA ccitt4>
<!ENTITY ent3 SYSTEM "Graphic/test4.txt" NDATA ccitt4>
]>
<test  id="01" >
</test>
```

I Have to find that ent1 is declared more than once .

For the moment we are using getEntities method

```
  NamedNodeMap entities = lJDocumentXML.getDoctype().getEntities();
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/DocumentType.html#getEntities()

Which do not returns duplicate entity (it returns only ent1 ,ent2 and ent3) and external entity if any in the referenced dtd

Is there any way to get all the four entities ?

Thanks
 Atul

Answer (score 1):

"DocumentType" **discard duplicates** of attributes "entities" and "notations" by Interface Definition (see W3C DOM Spec. [W3C SPEC - REC-DOM-Level-3-Core](https://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-DOM-Level-3-Core-20040407/core.html#ID-412266927))

> A NamedNodeMap containing the general entities, both external and
>   internal, declared in the DTD. Parameter entities are not contained.
>   Duplicates are discarded. For example in:
>
> ```
> <!DOCTYPE ex SYSTEM "ex.dtd" [
>   <!ENTITY foo "foo">
>   <!ENTITY bar "bar">
>   <!ENTITY bar "bar2">
>   <!ENTITY % baz "baz">
> ]>
> <ex/>
> ```
>
> the interface provides access to foo and the first declaration of bar
>   but not the second declaration of bar or baz. Every node in this map
>   also implements the Entity interface. The DOM Level 2 does not support
>   editing entities, therefore entities cannot be altered in any way.

I think that you need to use another method to parse/check this information... e.g. you can use a regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

As @Ariel mentioned, "DocumentType" discard duplicates of attributes "entities" and "notations" by default..

Hence you can write a custom function like this..

```
String fileStr = FileUtils.readFileToString(file);
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<!ENTITY.+SYSTEM");       
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(fileStr);
ArrayList<String> stringArrayList = new ArrayList <>();
while(matcher.find())
{
    String matchedStr = matcher.group();
        matchedStr = matchedStr.replace("<!ENTITY","");  
        matchedStr = matchedStr.replace("SYSTEM","");     
        matchedStr = matchedStr.trim();
        if(stringArrayList.contains(matchedStr))
        {
                   //actions to be taken for duplicates
        }
        stringArrayList.add(matchedStr);
    }
```